# How to increment i in for loop in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, increment

I'm trying to modify the code below so each first number in column is based on the row number.

```
int i, sum = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < 7;  row++)
{
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
    sum = 0;                
}

Console.Read();
```

presents this in console:

```
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
1 2 3 4 5 15
```

But I'm trying get like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 sum
2 3 4 5 6 sum
3 4 5 6 7 sum
4 5 6 7 8 sum
and so on..
......
....
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: you're starting each row, in your inner loop, with `i = 1`. Maybe that's something you can change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the inner loop to be

```
for (int i = row + 1; i < row + 6; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
sum = sum + i;
Console.Write("{0} ", i);
```

enter code here

with

```
number = number + row
sum = sum + number;
Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

This way you use the variable row to keep track of the starting number for the row.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the console statements and just the sum, you can just use no inner loop and:

```
sum = Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Range(row+1, 5));
```

It's LINQ

or, if you need the console statement:

```
Enumerable.Range(row+1, 5).ToList().ForEach(c => sum += c; Console.Write(c));
```

Comment: Suggesting LINQ and lambdas to a brand new programmer? They're still trying to grok for-loops.

Comment: i think the point should be considered that most of us began programming in an environment where those concepts didnt exist...there might be a time where someone considers these concepts synonymous instead of a step up @DavidMakogon

Comment: Point being, they had the start point of the loop incorrect. Your solution was a complete departure from their code, dove into enumerables, linq, lambda. This in no way corrects their code. It's a rewrite. Might be an obvious solution for a seasoned developer. But the answer is not in line with their question and level of competence in c#. It's great that you can provide such a succinct answer; just that it's out of context for this question.

Comment: An old school mentality like that will definitely mean you select an rb at 2...go iggles